# Free Alternative to Logger Pro

Tags: gratis, data-visualization, logs, data-analysis, data

I'm looking for a free alternative to [Logger Pro](http://www.vernier.com/products/software/lp/) from Vernier. I would like it to have the same features as Logger Pro does, including but not limited to,

- Simple UI
- Collect and Analysis Data
- Perform data analysis, such as statistical analysis, curve fitting, 
  and calculated columns
- Add pictures to lab reports
- Add movies and synchronize movies with data collection
- Manually enter data
- Export data to Excel® or other spreadsheets

The application does *not* have to have all these features but it would be great if it did.
I would like this application to run on Windows 10 64bit.

Any recommendations are most welcome (with the exception of [Logger Lite](http://www.vernier.com/products/software/logger-lite/))

Answer (score 0):

Tracker is a free open software, similar to LoggerPro.

https://physlets.org/tracker/

With tracker, you can open gifs / movies and make annotations on each frame, such as marking points or vectors, then export that data into something easily readable, like *.csv format (compatabile with Excel). This synchronized annotation and collection of data from frames of movies was what brought me to that tool.

While it lacks many of the bells and whistles of LoggerPro, it has the majority of your requested features, and has served me well enough for freeware.